# squeeze raspberry pi zero w for stockfish

Tags: pi-zero-w

I am trying to run stockfish and get it as fast as possible to what I consider "good values", at least over 20 deep.
I'm using a raspberry pi zero w ... and after 20 seconds it's only 12 deep.
How could I make it faster? I don't need to have a desktop or "anything" just run stockfish.
Thanks.

Comment: What is stockfish? Is 20 a realistic goal for a single core with 512 MB of Ram? How is performance tuning this app any different than if it was run on a Linux PC?

Comment: Stockfish is a chess engine that run on console. Is realistic, because you can wait... so, i want to wait the less time.... just that.

Answer (score 1):

A Pi zero is not known for its performance or extendability. You could try some tuning, with `vmstat`, `top` and `iostat`, but your options are limited.

- kill everything you don't need. You might even go to slackware to remove the systemd-performance hit
- If you have a memory shortage, you could invest in a swap device on USB, separate from your sd card
- And perhaps a bit of overclocking if your're CPU bound.
- You could also look at a faster sd card.

But that basically are all your options.

Comment: "the systemd-performance hit" -> That's funny because I thought slackware still used the generally *slower* (as far as "speed" is really a serious factor in an init daemon) sysvinit.  If you want to privilege a task, just killing other things willy-nilly is not a very good strategy.  You prioritize it with `nice`, or use realtime scheduling, or dedicate processor cores and/or time slices to it (eg. via namespaces), etc.